# Is there a way to update the PasswordAnswer when using the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership API?

Tags: membership

Is there a way to update the PasswordAnswer when using the ASP.NET 2.0 Membership API? I want to be clear, I'm not trying to change the password, but rather I'm trying the give the user the option to update the Security Question and Security Answer they specified when enrolling.

Answer (score 0):

The base MembershipProvider class has an overridable method called ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer. You can use this to change the security question and answer. The signature looks like so:

```
public override bool ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(string username, string password, string newPasswordQuestion, string newPasswordAnswer)
    {
        // your implementation here.
    }
```